# How to update DataGrid's ItemsSource based on ListBox selection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I have a ListBox and DataGrid.

I am trying to change ItemsSource of the DataGrid when I change the selection in ListBox.
Example: If I select the first item in the ListBox Collection1 should be binded to DataGrid's ItemsSource. If I select 2nd item Collection2 should be binded to the DataGrid's ItemsSource.

Below is what I tried

View - Xaml

```
<ListBox 
    Grid.Column="0" 
    Width="100" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding coll1}" 
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName}">
</ListBox>
<DataGrid 
    Grid.Column="1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding coll, Mode=TwoWay}">
</DataGrid>`
```

View Model -

```
public class VM1
    {
        private List<Employee> _coll = new List<Employee>();
        public List<Employee> coll
        {
            get
            {
                return _coll;
            }
            set
            {
                coll = value;
            }
        }

        public List<string> _coll1 = new List<string>();

        public List<string> coll1
        {
            get
            {
                return _coll1;
            }
        }

        private string _selectedName = "";
        public string SelectedName 
        {
            get
            {
                return _selectedName;
            }
            set
            {
                _selectedName = value;
            }
        }

        public VM1()
        {
            _coll.Add(new Employee());
            _coll.Add(new Employee());
            _coll.Add(new Employee());

            _coll1.Add("One");
            _coll1.Add("Two");
            _coll1.Add("Three");
        }

    }
```

Model -

```
 public class Employee
    {
        public Employee()
        {
            Name = "Hello";
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Look for INotifyPropertyChanged that is the root for binding update notification.

Comment: What are `Collection1` and `Collection2`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind ItemsSource of the DataGrid to the property of your view model which will be changed according to SelectedName. Something like this:

```
public class VM1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private IEnumerable _collection;
    private string _selectedName;

    public IEnumerable Collection
    {
        get { return _collection; }
        set
        {
            _collection = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Collection)));
        }
    }

    public string SelectedName 
    {
        get { return _selectedName; }
        set
        {
            _selectedName = value;

            // Set Collection property based on the _selectedName
            if (_selectedName == "A")
                Collection = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }; // Collection 1
            else if (_selectedName == "B")
                Collection = new[] { 4, 5, 6 }; // Collection 2
        }
    }
}
```

Then just bind DataGrid to the Collection:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Collection, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, this is to set you on Right track:

**XAML**

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox x:Name="lstOfCollections"
             Width="100"
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
    </ListBox>
    <DataGrid DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=lstOfCollections,Path=SelectedItem}">
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

and this is `MainViewModel` used for `dataContext`

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        //Initializing collections
        Coll1 = new ObservableCollection<Employee> {
            new Employee { Name = "Coll1" },
            new Employee { Name = "Coll1" },
            new Employee { Name = "Coll1" },
        };
        Coll2 = new ObservableCollection<Employee> {
            new Employee { Name = "Coll2" },
            new Employee { Name = "Coll2" },
            new Employee { Name = "Coll2" },
        };
        Coll3 = new ObservableCollection<Employee> {
            new Employee { Name = "Coll3" },
            new Employee { Name = "Coll3" },
            new Employee { Name = "Coll3" },
        };

        Collection.Add(Coll1);
        Collection.Add(Coll2);
        Collection.Add(Coll3);
    }
    //collection1
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Coll1 { get; set; }
    //collection2
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Coll2 { get; set; }
    //collection3
    public ObservableCollection<Employee> Coll3 { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<object> Collection { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<object>();
}
```

and class Employee for populating those collections with some data.

```
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

[[image: coll1 selected] [image: coll2 selected] [image: coll3 selected]